# How to execute Python code from file with a backslash character in it

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to run Python 3.3 code from a file with paths ("C:\Users\Documents\ect.") in it. When I try to run exec(commands), it returns this error:

```
tuple: ("(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position ...
```

which I know is because of the single backslash character in the file paths, I know it works if it is backslashbackslash instead, but I don't know how to swap backslashbackslash for backslash. My code looks something like this:

```
filepath = HardDrive + "/Folder/" + UserName + "/file.txt"
file = open(filepath, 'r')
commands = file.read()
exec(commands)
```

The file simply has a command like this in it

```
os.remove("C:\Users\Documents\etc.")
```

The file path in the function in the file is returned automatically and I have no control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a raw string `r` using `str.replace` to escape the filename inside the file:

```
with open("{}/Folder/{}/file.txt".format(HardDrive, UserName)) as f:
     (exec(f.read().replace("C:\\",r"C:\\")))
```

Now the filename will look like `'C:\\Users\\Documents\\etc.`'.

You also may need to remove that period:

```
exec(f.read().rstrip(".").replace("C:\\",r"C:\\"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```
commands = commands.replace('\\', '/')
```

placed just before the `exec(commands)` would fix the problem **if** it's indeed all about the presence of backslashes (as it will turn each and every one of them into a forward slash).

Of course that's a problem if there are in the file also backslashes you want to keep as such (this simple code can't distinguish which ones you want to keep, which ones to replace!) but from your problem description this should not bother you in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **r** before your path, it will ignore all escape characters.

```
os.remove(r"C:\Users\Documents\etc.")
```

Like this.So,

```
file = open(r"filepath", 'r')
```

Beyond that, both Windows and Linux accepting `/` this for file paths. So you should use this. Not `\`, use this one `/`.

After your comment here;

```
file = open(r"{}".format(filepath), 'r')
```

Assume your variable is;

```
filepath = "c:\users\tom"
```

Put **r** before it and;

```
filepath = r"c:\users\tom"
```

Then use;

```
file = open(r"{}".format(filepath), 'r')
```

My final edit after you edited your question.

```
filepath = r"{}/Folder/{}/file.txt".format(HardDrive,UserName)
file = open(r"{}".format(filepath), 'r')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience, but it returns the exact same error. It's really frustrating!